# Print a line on demand without variable in it using format processor

Tags: perl, format

I'm writing a protocol unsing the format processor of perl.

So I have a format like

```
format err_spooler_line =
@#### | Error: ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
$error_spooler_line, $error_spooler_text_short
~~    | ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        $error_spooler_text_short
# --> This line should only displayed, when $error_spooler_text_long is set.
      | Details:
~~    | ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        $error_spooler_text_long
.
```

As **workaround** I use:

```
format err_spooler_line =
@#### | Error: ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
$error_spooler_line, $error_spooler_text_short
~~    | ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        $error_spooler_text_short
# --> This line should only displayed, when $error_spooler_text_long is set.
# So it is working, but it writes some text of the description in the line
~     | Details: ^<
                 $error_spooler_text_long
~~    | ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        $error_spooler_text_long
.
```

If I start my description test with `\n` it works:
`$error_spooler_text_long = "\n" . $error_spooler_text_long`. So after "Details" there is a linebreak and the next line starts with the next picture line.

But how can I do this automatically? So that there is no need of prefix my string with an `\n`.

### A complete example:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;

# Variables used in the format
my $error_spooler_line;
my $error_spooler_text_short;
my $error_spooler_text_long;

format err_spooler_top =
Protocol: - DATA-Error                              Page: @###
                                                          $%
--------------------------------------------------------------
.

format err_spooler_line  =
@#### | Error: ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
$error_spooler_line, $error_spooler_text_short
~~    | ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                     $error_spooler_text_short
      | Details:
~~    | ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        $error_spooler_text_long
.

# The whole protocol is written into a string.
my $error_file_string = "";
open my $hnd_spooler, ">", \$error_file_string;

select((select($hnd_spooler),
        $~ = "err_spooler_line",
        $^ = "err_spooler_top"
       )[0]);
       
    
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;

    $error_spooler_line = $.;
    ($error_spooler_text_short, $error_spooler_text_long) = split (/;/);
    write $hnd_spooler;   
}

close ($hnd_spooler);

## Now, all the protocol is in $error_file_string !
print $error_file_string;

__DATA__
ERR_ID_0   OK;
ERR_ID_278 UPDATE Failed;Update failed cause of DB connection error\nDB error number: 22.
ERR_ID_0   OK;
ERR_ID_33  Invalid data format;Only numbers allowed.
```

The output is then:

```txt
Protocol: - DATA-Error                              Page:    1
--------------------------------------------------------------
    1 | Error: ERR_ID_0   OK
      | Details:
    2 | Error: ERR_ID_278 UPDATE Failed
      | Details:
      | Update failed cause of DB connection error\nDB error
      | number: 22.
    3 | Error: ERR_ID_0   OK
      | Details:
    4 | Error: ERR_ID_33  Invalid data format
      | Details:
      | Only numbers allowed.
```

But I want to have the "Details:" line only it there are Details:

```txt
Protocol: - DATA-Error                              Page:    1
--------------------------------------------------------------
    1 | Error: ERR_ID_0   OK
    2 | Error: ERR_ID_278 UPDATE Failed
      | Details:
      | Update failed cause of DB connection error
      | DB error number: 22.
    3 | Error: ERR_ID_0   OK
    4 | Error: ERR_ID_33  Invalid data format
      | Details:
      | Only numbers allowed.
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data for different input variables, and also the expected output. See [mcve] for more information

Comment: Showing the output you get and the output you want would help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [perlform](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlform):

> Using caret fields can produce lines where all fields are blank. You
> can suppress such lines by putting a "~" (tilde) character anywhere in
> the line. The tilde will be translated to a space upon output.

The following seems to work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $error_spooler_line ;
my $error_spooler_text_short;
my $error_spooler_text_long;

format err_spooler =
@#### | Error: ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
$error_spooler_line, $error_spooler_text_short
~~    | ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        $error_spooler_text_short
~     | ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
@{[(length $error_spooler_text_long) ? "Details:" : ""]}
~~    | ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        $error_spooler_text_long
.

select (STDOUT);
$~ = "err_spooler";
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    $error_spooler_line = $.;
    ($error_spooler_text_short, $error_spooler_text_long) = split /;/;
    write;
}


__DATA__
ERR_ID_0   OK;
ERR_ID_278 UPDATE Failed;Update failed cause of DB connection error, DB error number: 22.
ERR_ID_0   OK;
ERR_ID_33  Invalid data format;Only numbers allowed.
```

**Output**:

```
1 | Error: ERR_ID_0   OK
2 | Error: ERR_ID_278 UPDATE Failed
  | Details:
  | Update failed cause of DB connection error, DB error number: 22.
3 | Error: ERR_ID_0   OK
4 | Error: ERR_ID_33  Invalid data format
  | Details:
  | Only numbers allowed.
```

Comment: Thank you very much! `@{[(length $error_spooler_text_long) ? "Details:" : ""]}` that I need! I tried some possibilities like this but I always got an "Modification of a read-only value attempted" error. This works. Thanks!